# Dataflow job throws error when publishing to Pub/Sub topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have streaming Dataflow job that sink the output data to a pub/sub topic. But randomly the job logs throws an error:

```
There were errors attempting to publish to topic projects/my_project/topics/my_topics. Recent publish calls completed successfully: 574, recent publish calls completed with error: 1.
```

there is no stack trace provided by the dataflow, and from the job metrics the error type is "unavailable". After some time, the error will stopped and the pipeline still running as usual. Does this error occurs because of internal error in the GCP service, or because of quota issue? The output request was peaked at 10 req/s.

Comment: The PubsubIO should retry on failures, so you can ignore these errors. 10 QPS does not exceed the quota. You will see errors about rate limit exceeded in logs if you run out of quota. The error could be caused by PubSub service unavailable (as listed in your case) or timeout.

Answer (score -2):

Found the similar issue, it resolved by adding the "Pub/Sub Admin" permission to Compute Engine default service account under IAM permissions.

Comment: I have done that but the error still randomly occurs